# Update multiple elements of array in mongodb document with appropriate element of javascript array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation

I have array of objects with following structure:

```
const myArr = [{
'name':'question1',
'grade':6
},
{
'name':'question2',
'grade':7
}]
```

**Question collection**:

```
{
_id:623749f845844e7d273d801c,
questions:[
{
'name':'question1',
'grade':10,
'someInfo':'blabla',
_id:623749f845844e7d273d801m
},
{
'name':'question2',
'grade':10,
'someInfo':'blabla',
_id:623749f845844e7d273d801a
},
{
'name':'question3',
'grade':10,
'someInfo':'blabla',
_id:623749f845844e7d273d801f
}
]
}
```

I just want to update all objects in array `questions` in collection which i have provided in `myArr` array. So the **desired result** should be:

```
{
    _id:623749f845844e7d273d801c,
    questions:[
    {
    'name':'question1',
    'grade':6,
    'someInfo':'blabla',
    _id:623749f845844e7d273d801m
    },
    {
    'name':'question2',
    'grade':7,
    'someInfo':'blabla',
    _id:623749f845844e7d273d801a
    },
    {
    'name':'question3',
    'grade':10,
    'someInfo':'blabla',
    _id:623749f845844e7d273d801f
    }
    ]
}
```

**What i've found** so far: 
I managed to update `grade` when i specify the `question name` with positional operator:

```
    await Prijave.updateOne(
    {
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(q_id),
      'questions.name': 'question1',
    },
    {
      $set: {
        'questions.$.grade': '10',
      },
    }
  )
```

But how to do this for every element in `myArr` ? I could make `forEach` loop which iterates through `myArr`and call `updateOne` for every element but i dont think it should be done that way because it will make multiple connection to database instead of one.